# Train accuracy of Tensorflow model remains at zero

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, classification, training-data

i build a model based on this [architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75Tq1.jpg) to make a binary classification [**"0"** for **"Delay-insensitive"**, **"1"** for **"Interactive"**] using **5 features**.  The target column is **vmcategory**. When I train the model the accuracy remain at zero.

You can check the [my colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BSdnj_1TtNSrZKJSjNAUmWvW5n2Cyobr?usp=sharing) here please.

```
Epoch 1/100
1/1 [==============================] - 29s 29s/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 0.6893 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 0.6808 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 0.6571 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 0.5957 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 0.5372 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 0.3760 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 0.2411 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 0.1913 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 0.0571 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 0.0483 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 12/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 0.0088 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 13/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 6.1697e-04 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 14/100
1/1 [==============================] - 6s 6s/step - loss: 3.2386e-04 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 15/100
1/1 [==============================] - 6s 6s/step - loss: 6.8086e-06 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 16/100
1/1 [==============================] - 6s 6s/step - loss: 7.7796e-05 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 17/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 1.1021e-06 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 18/100
1/1 [==============================] - 6s 6s/step - loss: 2.7273e-07 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 87/100
1/1 [==============================] - 6s 6s/step - loss: 1.0003e-13 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 88/100
1/1 [==============================] - 6s 6s/step - loss: 2.6685e-14 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 89/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 2.4792e-12 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 90/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 1.2417e-13 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 91/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 1.4707e-11 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 92/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 4.9625e-14 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 93/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 3.7239e-13 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 94/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 6.0243e-13 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 95/100
1/1 [==============================] - 6s 6s/step - loss: 1.4047e-11 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 96/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 1.0687e-14 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 97/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 3.4614e-16 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 98/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 4.5617e-11 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 99/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 1.5913e-14 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 100/100
1/1 [==============================] - 7s 7s/step - loss: 3.0236e-10 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using accuracy as metrics which expects class labels as input but you are providing class logits (or confidence) as input. Please replace `accuracy` with `tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()`

--Edit--

So, there is a different problem which i just noticed. You have 223461 such that the input features is a vector of 5 length and the aim is to do binary classification.

You are assuming the input samples as feature vectors and because of the same you are trying to predict 223461 classes. To fix this you would need to do the following changes

Make the following changes in the architecture,

```
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid')) # here n_outputs should be 1
```

- Remove the Conv1D and GRU layers, your input features are tabular and does not need Convolutional operations.
- Replace the softmax function with sigmoid as you are doing binary classification.
- Replace the CategoricalAccuracy with 'accuracy'
- Ensure your data is of shape [X_batch, 5]
- Ensure your y is of shape [X_batch, 1]

here, X_batch could be of shape [223461, 5] and in complex models you might not process the whole data in a single loop and would use a small batch size.

Comment: still have the same issue 
`Epoch 1/100
1/1 [==============================] - 20s 20s/step - loss: 0.6932 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/100
1/1 [==============================] - 8s 8s/step - loss: 0.6906 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/100
1/1 [==============================] - 8s 8s/step - loss: 0.6835 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00


`

Comment: hi, i have updated my answer; it should work post these changes but it might not too like you would have to study the foundation of tensorflow and machine learning.

Comment: like i said i shoud have the same architecture like in this [picture](https://imgur.com/a/99P5m6S) so I could not remove the Conv1D and GRU layers like you said .

Comment: your data doesn't seem to have a time series

Comment: i'm trying to remake this model [here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2106/2106.12178.pdf) with the dataset [here](https://github.com/Azure/AzurePublicDataset/blob/master/AzurePublicDatasetV2.md)